Pico flash and heap - how much available and how much is used
I am learning how to program a Raspberry PicoW in C++ and I have two question about flash:

How much of the flash is my programme taking up?  With AtMega programming, the compiler would display this as a %, but I don't get that with the pico SDK and I would like to know how much bigger my programme can be.

And how much of the heap in the flash is available?  Is there memory available to heap some large arrays?


From the data sheet, the pico-w has 2MB of flash.
The uf2 file for my programme is 924Kb.  Can I assume that my application is taking up about 924Kb of the 2Mb of flash?  (~50%)
I found some functions to examine the flash:
struct mallinfo mi;
mi = mallinfo();

which gives:
Total non-mmapped bytes (arena): 51232
Total allocated space (uordblks): 44272
Total free space (fordblks): 6960
Does this mean I have about 51K of heap, and about 7K free?  About 14%.  I create a large buffer on the heap (41K), so that would explain the allocated space.
I also found this pair of functions:
uint32_t getFreeHeap()
{
    struct mallinfo m = mallinfo();
    return _getTotalHeap() - m.uordblks;
}

uint32_t _getTotalHeap()
{
    extern char __StackLimit, __bss_end__;
    return &__StackLimit - &__bss_end__;
}

_getTotalHeap() -> 243744
_getFreeHeap() -> 199472
243744 - 199472 = 44272
Do these numbers show that I have 44K available of the 244K of heap (~18%)?
Thank you for reading.

I think this question is too broad because you're asking both about flash and about RAM, which are two totally separate spaces.  RAM is where the heap is, and malloc always returns a pointer to RAM, not flash.  Flash cannot be quickly or easily written to and it has limited erase/write cycles.  How about you split this into two questions, one about flash and one about RAM?  That makes it much easier for someone attempting to answer.

Thanks for the reply.  Yes, I'll split up the question.  I thought the code was loaded into the flash, and what flash the programme didn't use up was then then heap.  I have since found there is another chip on the pico for memory.

"heap in the flash", heap refer to the memory space that is dynamically allocated in RAM, not in flash memory. For MCU, code executed directly from flash, only variables that are defined not as const get load into RAM, if the variable is statically allocated like uint32_t t = 0;, it is allocated in the stack. If it is dynamic allocated with malloc(), it is allocated in the heap.
